# How to import custom attribute types and objectclasses to OpenDJ 3.0?

Tags: opendj

I have `OpenDJ v3.0.0` and need to import custom `attribute types`and `objectclasses` from `OUD - Oracle Unified Directory`. Unfortunately I can't use `GUI - Control Panel` due to a problem with `x11`.

```
/tmp/attribute_types_oud.txt
===================
dn: cn=schema
attributetypes: ( 2.5.4.19 NAME 
'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' EQUALITY 
caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch 
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128} X-ORIGIN 
'RFC 4519' )
....

/tmp/objectclasses_oud.txt
===================
dn: cn=schema
objectclasses: ( 2.5.6.0 NAME 'top' ABSTRACT MUST 
objectClass X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4512' )
...
```

I tried to add both attribute types and objectclasses into `99-user.ldif` under `/install_path/config/schema` then restart its service and tried to import `users data` but it didn't make a difference.

Can someone teach me how to import them?

Comment: First any standard base schema is already defined in OpenDJ, so you should not try to add it again.You should only extend schema with whatever was customized in OUD. You do not "import" schema, you simply copy the 99-user.ldif file from OUD to OpenDJ config/schema directory (when the server is stopped).

Comment: oh..I see...I appreciate expanding my poor understanding on ldap schema. I will follow your suggestion. Above all, Ty for taking your precious time to reply to a stranger with bombarding questions. Wish for best.